# How do I find out if two lists have the same attributes in python?

Tags: python

For my coding project I have to take this code and see if there are any similar attributes. If it does,
I need a print statement saying "The lists have similar attributes" and if it doesn't then there should be a print statement saying "the two statements have the same attributes."

```py
class Box:
    def __init__(self, date1, contents1, location1):
        self.date = date1
        self.contents = contents1
        self.location = location1


box23 = Box("2016", "medical records", "storage closet")
box21 = Box("2018", "lotion samples", "waiting room")
box07 = Box("2020", "flyers for flu shot", "receptionist desk")
print(box23.date)
print(box21.contents)
print(box07.location)
```

Comment: What? What lists? And what list attributes? Lists have no data attributes - they have a bunch of methods, and stuff like `__class__`, but that's it.

Comment: What lists? What's the intended output here?

Comment: box23, box21, and box07 are lists, right?

Comment: I just want to have an if else statement here.

Comment: not at all, they are Box objects

Comment: No, they're instances of `Box`.

Comment: is there a way to figure out if they have the same attributes?

Comment: you want to know if all attributes are the same or only one specific attribute?

Comment: just one specific attribute

Comment: Are you wanting to ask if they have similar values set as parameters? Your example shows three objects, all with different values.

Comment: just do like `if box23.date == box07.date: ...`

Comment: no, i just want a if/else statement that tells me that the atributes are not the same/ are the same

Comment: what do i put for else?

Comment: i have else
print ("box21 and 07 do not have similer attributes")

Comment: i gives me an error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare a single attribute you can do it with

```
if box23.date == box21.date:
    print("boxes have the same date")
else:
    print("boxes have different dates")
```

If you want to compare all attributes you can simply compare the `__dict__` attribute:

```
if box23.__dict__ == box21.__dict__:
    print("boxes have the same attributes")
else:
    print("boxes don't have the same attributes")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all attributes which are at both objects:

```
def get_matching_attributes(instance1, instance2):
    return [attribute for attribute in instance1.__dict__ if attribute in instance2.__dict__]
```

-> returns a list of all matching attributes

---

If you want to get all attributes which are at both objects *and* also have the same value:

*Ensure you also got the function `get_matching_attributes` as defined above for usage*

```
def compare_matched_attribute_values(instance1, instance2):
    matching_attributes = get_matching_attributes(instance1, instance2)
    matching_values = []
    for attribute in matching_attributes:
        if instance1.__dict__[attribute] == instance2.__dict__[attribute]:
            matching_values.append((attribute, True))
        else:
            matching_values.append((attribute, False))
    return [obj[0] for obj in matching_values if obj[1] is True]
```

-> returns a list of all matching attributes which also have the same value

*Hint: change the last column to `return matching_values` if you want to get a list of all matching attributes inside a tuble with `True` or  `False` indicating if the attribute got the same value in both objects.*